# A skew symmetric and orthogonal matrix has eigen values (3/5) + (4i/5). How can this be possible? It must have 0 or purely imaginary values. Problem 1

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Problem 1. It is Orthogonal and skew symmetric but eigen values aren't purely imaginary or zero

Are the following matrices symmetric, skew-symmetric and/or orthogonal?
$$\frac15\begin{bmatrix}3&-4\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matrix is not skew-symmetric, the diagonal entries are non-zero.

Comment: Thanks the solution on the back said it is a skew symmetric matrix so I got confused.